# What is the safest way to install idris with cabal now

Tags: installation, sandbox, ghc, cabal, idris

I would like to install the idris toolchain, and since I have cabal installed and setup I tried to install it with `cabal install`

But when I run `cabal install idris`, it result in the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: idris-1.3.3 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: idris:setup.Cabal (dependency of idris)
[__1] rejecting: idris:setup.Cabal-3.2.1.0/installed-3.2.1.0 (conflict: idris
=> idris:setup.Cabal>=2.4 && <3.1)
[__1] skipping: idris:setup.Cabal-3.4.0.0, idris:setup.Cabal-3.2.1.0,
idris:setup.Cabal-3.2.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the
previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=2.4 && <3.1' from 'idris')
[__1] rejecting: idris:setup.Cabal-3.0.2.0, idris:setup.Cabal-3.0.1.0,
idris:setup.Cabal-3.0.0.0, idris:setup.Cabal-2.4.1.0,
idris:setup.Cabal-2.4.0.1, idris:setup.Cabal-2.4.0.0,
idris:setup.Cabal-2.2.0.1, idris:setup.Cabal-2.2.0.0,
idris:setup.Cabal-2.0.1.1, idris:setup.Cabal-2.0.1.0,
...
idris:setup.Cabal-1.2.2.0, idris:setup.Cabal-1.2.1, idris:setup.Cabal-1.1.6,
idris:setup.Cabal-1.24.1.0 (constraint from minimum version of Cabal used by
Setup.hs requires >=3.2)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: idris, idris:setup.Cabal)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: idris:setup.Cabal, idris, base, ivor`
```

I know that the language is a bit out-dated compared to today's haskell packages.

Some people installed it in a sandbox with an oldest version of cabal, but I don't now what is the right way to do it now, with nix-style v2-install in new cabal-install.

- Cabal version :

```
cabal-install version 3.4.0.0
compiled using version 3.4.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

How should I install idris ?

Is it better to get it pre-compiled from the AUR (I'm on archlinux)?

Comment: https://github.com/Idris-lang/Idris2/